# Running Django syncdb and migrations with Chef

Tags: django, deployment, chef-infra, fabric

We are moving towards deploying our Django apps with Chef. One question I have is what is the best way to handle the following commands:

```
./manage.py syncdb
./manage.py migrate --noinput
./manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

I'm using the [application](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/application) cookbook. We normally handled these with a Fabric script, and I'd like to continue using Fabric if possible. Is there a best practice on how to handle this? Use a callback such as `before_restart` to execute the Fabric commands to syncdb, migrate, and collectstatic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [cookbook](http://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/application_python) contains an attribute called `migration_command`